# PostgresException: 42703: column "x" of relation "y" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run stored procedure from .net core, it gives me an error saying:

> PostgresException: 42703: column "AcceptanceActID" of relation "AcceptanceActLines" does not exist

This is the query I am trying run:

```
create or replace function "ClosePeriod"(month integer, year integer) 
returns void
    language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN

INSERT INTO billing."AcceptanceActs"("AccountID", "Month",  "Year","Amount")
SELECT
    DISTINCT th."AccountID",
    "month",
    "year",
    th."TotalAmount"


FROM billing."TransactionHeaders" AS th
    WHERE th."AcceptanceActID" IS NULL;


UPDATE billing."TransactionHeaders" set "AcceptanceActID" = acc."ID" from 
billing."AcceptanceActs" acc
    where acc."Year"="year" AND acc."Month"="month" AND 
    acc."AccountID"=billing."TransactionHeaders"."AccountID"
    AND billing."TransactionHeaders"."AcceptanceActID" is null;


INSERT INTO billing."AcceptanceActLines"("PackageId","Amount","AcceptanceActID")
SELECT
    tl."PackageID",
    SUM(tl."Amount"),
    aa."ID"
FROM billing."TransactionHeaders" AS th
INNER JOIN billing."TransactionLines" AS tl ON th."Id" = tl."TransactionHeaderID"
INNER JOIN billing."AcceptanceActs" as aa ON th."AcceptanceActID" = 
aa."ID"
    WHERE aa."Month"=="month" AND aa."Year"=="year"
    GROUP BY tl."PackageID", aa."ID";

END;
$$;

 alter function "ClosePeriod"(integer, integer) owner to postgres;
```

I saw similar questions on the internet and couldn't fit any solution with my problem.

Comment: Pretty sure none of this is C# or ASP.NET Core related. Does the SQL actually run on it's own?

Comment: Are the column and table name actually capitalized like you have them in your script?

Comment: @DavidG No. SQL gives me the same error.

Comment: @Jeremy Yes. columns and table names are capitalized

Comment: Then you need to debug your SQL and remove references to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Can you show your table definition?  Does the user running the function have usage privileges on the billing schema?

Comment: There is no ambiguity in the error message; the column you're trying to reference does not exist. Given the inconsistent use of `ID` v.s. `Id` across your schema, a difference in capitalisation seems like a likely cause.